# How to remove "Shipping & Handling" and " Tax" on email transactional?

Tags: magento2, email, email-templates, tax

I wish to remove these elements :

[image: email]

Here is the tax configuration :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The totals in that gray box are populated from:

- vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/order/totals.phtml

Copy that file to your theme:

- app/design/frontend/vendor//Magento_Sales/templates/order/totals.phtml

Now you can skip the "Shipping and Handling" or "tax" sections with a continue statement:

```
...
<?php foreach ($block->getTotals() as $_code => $_total) : ?>
    <?php if ($_code === 'shipping' || $_code === 'tax') {
        continue;
    } ?>
    <?php if ($_total->getBlockName()) : ?>
...
```

Hope that helps someone!